# In UWP or Store app how to determine which .NET Framework Versions are installed

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, registry, .net-framework-version

So I'd like to print in my log for either build of my application (UWP app and also Windows Store app) the installed .NET Framework Versions on the system running the application when it starts up.

All resources pretty much point to using the registry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

That isn't possible in the Windows Store application, since the RegistryKey class isn't available.

Is there another way to do get at the installed .Net Framework versions so I can print the results in the log?

Comment: Why do you want to do so while UWP does not require .NET Framework at all. A sandboxed app like that shouldn't do such things.

Comment: I suppose you're right, but lets not forget about the Windows Store app build as well, does this fall into the same set of constraints as UWP?

Comment: UWP is "Windows Store app 2.0". I see no major difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that UWP means also smartphone or XBOX, not only desktop/tablet X64. You don't need the .NET Framework installed. Maybe you can check something about adaptive code or "Windows Desktop Extension for the UWP".